# Puede el verbo "cocinar" ser conjugado de forma pronominal?

Tags: verbos

Hoy yo vi la siguiente frase:

> Cocinar-te es un acto de amor propio.

Claramente, el *cocinar-te* en la frase quiere decir *cocinar para uno mismo*.

Como no soy hispanoablante nativo, me pareció rara esta conjugación. En portugués, el verbo *cozinhar* es transitivo e intransitivo, con el caso transitivo refiriéndose a lo que va a ser cocinado. Así, *cozinhar-se* significaría que vos estás cocinándote a vos mismo, una conjugación reflexiva y, semánticamente, macabra.

Podemos añadir la preposición *para* con el intento de decir quién va a comer de lo que está siendo cocinado.

Ejemplo:

> Vou cozinhar arroz para você!

En este caso, el objeto directo del verbo *cozinhar* es el arroz, en cuanto que la persona que va a comerlo es *você* (usted).

En español, [según el diccionario de la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/cocinar?m=form), el verbo *cocinar* también es transitivo y puede ser usado como intransitivo. Pero no pude encontrar nada sobre el uso pronominal de este verbo con el sentido de "cocinar para".

¿Es esta una construcción aceptable? Si es así, ¿dónde puedo obtener este tipo de información para saber en cuáles casos lo es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es correcto decir "cocinarse" para indicar, como bien dice la pregunta, "cocinar para uno mismo". En este caso, la partícula -se funciona como complemento indirecto (para quién se cocina).

Esto no significa que el verbo clasifique como "pronominal". Un verbo pronominal es aquel que, sin ser reflexivo y sin ser el sujeto el destinatario o beneficiario de la acción, adopta la partícula -se (o la que corresponda según la persona). [En esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Linguistik/v/VERBOS%20PRONOMINALES.htm) se pueden encontrar varias definiciones y ejemplos de verbos pronominales (antiguamente se los llamaba "cuasirreflejos").

Existe, no obstante, un uso pronominal y muy coloquial de "cocinarse", que significa "morirse de calor":

- Encerrado en el auto y con 50 grados de temperatura, me estoy cocinando.

Otro verbo que se usa de esta forma y con este mismo sentido es "asarse". También "derretirse".

Nota: En respuesta a las dudas expresadas en el comentario:

(1) ¿Cómo puedo saber si la persona está cocinando para sí mismo o SE está cocinando a sí mismo? En ambos los casos se conjugaría "cocinarse". ¿La distinción sería únicamente por el contexto?
RESPUESTA: Un verbo pronominal NO es reflexivo. Una persona que se está muriendo de calor se está cocinando (NO decimos que se está cocinando a sí misma, salvo que sea un suicida y se haya metido dentro de un horno encendido). Además, en el primer caso puede aparecer el complemento directo (lo que se está cocinando)
Ejemplo:
Te veo acalorado // Me estoy cocinando (ambiguo: puede ser que la persona se esté cocinando algo en el horno, o que esté muerta de calor) / Me estoy cocinando un pastel (me: complemento indirecto / un pastel: complemento directo): desaparece la ambigüedad.

(2) El verbo no es pronominal porque no exige el pronombre?
CORRECTO. El verbo es pronominal cuando lleva pronombre en ese uso, ej. sentarSE, pararSE

(3) Este fenómeno de la partícula -se funcionar como un complemento indirecto es generalizado o pasa con verbos específicos?
RESPUESTA: Esto se da con verbos que acepten complemento indirecto, o que acepten complementos directo e indirecto.

Comment: ¡Gracias por contestar! Me quedaron algunas dudas. (1) Como puedo saber si la persona está cocinando para si mismo o está cocinando a si mismo? En ambos los casos se conjugaria _concinarse_. La distinción seria unicamente por el contexto? (2) El verbo no es pronominal porque no exije el pronome? (3) Este fenómeno de la partícula -se funcionar como un complemento indirecto es generalizado o pasa con verbos específicos?